# OpenCV (C++) : How to imshow yuv file?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm learning OpenCV, in C++ but Something got wrong..

I want to imshow yuv file, but I got an error on my code.

code :

Mat img = imread("myimage.yuv");
imshow("img", img);

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a frame from YUV file in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231518/how-to-read-a-frame-from-yuv-file-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file first :

```
FILE *YUV_FILE = fopen( "YourPAth\\YourFileName.yuv", "rb" );
```

create a pointer :

```
char *databuffer = new char[ frameWidth*frameHeight*ChannelCount];
```

Then read data  using  `fread` to the pointer `databuffer`

Now you'll be able to create an opencv `Mat` using  :

```
 cv::Mat OpencvImage(Size(frameWidth, frameHeight), CV_8UC3, databuffer, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
```